# Why is l'Hopital's rule being used with $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Tags: limits

I just watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMtqUOjYk7Y and I have a few questions:

1. I did some research about l'Hopital's rule and isn't it only applicable if you have $\frac{0}0$. In the video, it is used with $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Why is this?
2. Wouldn't it be just be simpler to solve the problem to say $lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}x = 0$ so we have $lim_{x\to \infty} \;x^0 = 0$. Isn't this simpler?

Comment: The form $\infty^0$ is indeterminate.  You can't let $x$ go to $\infty$ in the exponent first and independently of the $x$ in the base.

Comment: Also, there is a version of LR that is perfectly fine for the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  After all, if $f(x)/g(x)$ has this form, consider $(1/g(x))/(1/f(x))$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a really basic question (I'm in 8th grade) but with is ${\infty}^0$ indeterminate?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^0 = 1$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also, you need to edit the problem to show exactly what it is you're confronting.  Clicking on a link isn't a permanent fix.

Comment: (1) The YT video might get deleted or might not be accessible later. You should include the relevant Details & Points in your Post to make it self-contained. (2) You should ask one question in one Post. Eg this Post can be about using LH rule with $\infty/\infty$ & next Post can have next Issue

Comment: You can edit your own question and do it this time.

Answer (score 2):

Why is $\infty^0$ indeterminate?
Because of examples like this:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/\ln(x)} = \infty^0\quad\text{??}
$$
In fact
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/\ln(x)} = e \approx 2.71828 .
$$
Computation...
$$
x^{1/\ln(x)} = \left(e^{\ln x}\right)^{1/\ln(x)} = e^1 = e .
$$

Answer (score 0):

To see that $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is indeterminate, just look at the following two limits:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

Does this mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}$?

Of course not because $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is indeterminate. :)